# Does the Kabbalah explain why David’s sin affected his children

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

I believe Rashi said in 2 Samuel 12 that due to David’s sin the king lost many children.

Why, according to Kabbalah, did David's sin have this affect on his children?

Comment: Probably because David localised his existence.